# tex4ht and colortbl

Tags: tex4ht, colortbl

The package `colortbl` steals my beloved horizontal rules in the longtable. When I run `tex4ht`.

```
% run: htlatex main.tex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c|c}
fooo & baaar \\\hline
baz &  morebaz\\\hline
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

The file above gives a beautiful html, but when I load the package `colortbl`, it eats my `\hline`.

Question: how to get the horizontal rules *and* use the package `colortbl`?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of the official tex4ht customisation but the hrules end up as empty table rows with distinctive ids  so you can add css rules such as

```
 #TBL-1-2-{ border-style: solid; border-bottom: 1pt; border-color: black;}
 #TBL-1-19-{ border-style: solid; border-bottom: 1pt; border-color: black;}
```

and the lines come back.

Comment: The id is not stable. If I add lines to the table, the ids will move....

Comment: yes I know, They are I think the table and row number, but its best I could do in the time available tonight. If someone posts a proper tex4ht customisation I'll delete this.

Comment: colortbl.4ht needs thorough rework. I am working on it, but not sure, when I'll be able to post a solution. As a workaround what you had suggested seems good enough than having nothing.