# tex4ht and colortbl creates a misplaced \noalign error

Tags: tex4ht, colortbl

It seems to be a problem still not solved (related to question [311689](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311689/tex4ht-does-not-show-top-and-bottom-rules-of-table-when-loading-colortbl-package) and [73508](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73508/tex4ht-and-colortbl)). The usage of `colortbl` package with `tex4ht` causes the error: `Misplaced \noalign`.

Here is a short example to reproduce the error:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\arrayrulecolor[gray]{.7}
\hline
test & 1 \\
test & 2 \\
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In the `.log` file I got:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\a:hline ->\ifx \ar:cnt \:UnDef \else \o:noalign: 
                                                  {\append:def \hline:s {\a:...
l.7 \hline
```

I've also tried to define a `.cfg` file to make the command `\arrayrulecolor` do nothing:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\renewcommand\arrayrulecolor[2][1]{\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Unfortunately it also did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
\catcode`\:=11
% default hline color is black
\def\hline:color{fff}
% redefine default table configuration and put the color rule 
\def\a:HBorder{<tr class="hline" style="border-top:1px solid \#\hline:color">}
% get the rule color and convert it to a CSS definition stored in \hline:color
\newcommand\tmp:arrayrulecolor[2][named]{\noalign{\convertcolorspec{#1}{#2}{HTML}\:tmp\global\let\hline:color\:tmp}}
% use \HLet to support picture tables
\HLet\arrayrulecolor\tmp:arrayrulecolor
% don't display <hr> elements in this \hline
\Css{tr.hline td hr{display:none}}
\catcode`\:=12
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The issue you had with your redefinition is that it needs to use the `\noalign` command. In this config file, we use it to covert the color definition to CSS format and save it in `\hline:color` macro. It can be then used to insert the color definition in the HTML file.

We don't redefine `\arrayrulecolor` directly, but using temporary macro and `\HLet` command. This method will keep the original macro and call it inside `\Picture` command. This is necessary for the `pic-tabular` option, which turns tables into pictures.

The `\a:HBorder` macro inserts code for hline rows. We use the saved color to insert CSS code that colors border.

Your gray `\hline` then looks like this:

```
<tr class='hline' style='border-top:1px solid #B2B2B2'>
```

And it is rendered in this way:

[image]